# mod_deflate not works on Apache 2.4.37

Tags: server, ubuntu-18.04, apache2.4, mod-deflate

I've installed Apache 2.4.37 via `ppa:ondrej/apache2` and can't make `mod_deflate` (gzip compression) works. I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 server.

mod_deflate is enabled in Apache:

```
sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep deflate
deflate_module (shared)
```

I placed code into `.htaccess`:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA,NE]
```

`.htaccess` is enabled by Apache config (and redirection works).

When I try: `curl -I -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://myserver/pokus.css`

is returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 12:20:00 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://myserver/pokus.css
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

So file is returned uncompressed.

I also tried to add deflate command directly into VirtualHost, different command like `SetOutputFilter DEFLATE`, but without success.

No error message in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Apache is restarted also without errors.

Any idea?